# Java cache in map vs list

Tags: java, caching

Currently in my legacy code i have cached some DB info in form of list `List<CachedObject>`.

`CachedObject` looks something like this

```
    public class CachedObject
    {
        private int id;
        private int id_type;
        private int id_other_type;

       // getters and setters
    }
```

Most of the time i am fetching one specific object via function:

```
public CachedObject getById( Integer id )
    {
        if( id != null )
            for ( CachedObject cachedObject : this.cachedObjectList )
                if( cachedObject.getId().equals( id ) )
                    return cachedObject;

        return null;

    }
```

My question is would it be better to cache object in `Map<Integer, CachedObject>`with `id` as key. My concern in that scenario is that my **other** getters from that list have to look like:

```
    public CachedObject getByIdType( Integer id )
    {
        if( id != null )
            for ( CachedObject cachedObject : cachedObjectList.values() )
                if( cachedObject.getId().equals( id ) )
                    return cachedObject;

        return null;

    }
```

I haven't done this before, because I really don't know drawbacks of this map cache, and it seems silly not to do this in the first place.

Comment: If you need to keep all maps consistent, then using multiple maps requires some synchronization if concurrency is involved. If so, then you'd want to use an [index and lock striping](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/IndexableCache) to retain consistency with reasonable performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `HashMap.values()` directly returns a Collection. There is no computation or data copying done. It's as fast as it can be.

So caching in form of HashMap is the thing to do in your case.

**But** consider that if in any case you want `List<CachedObject>` in your code

```
ArrayList<CachedObject> list = new ArrayList<CachedObject>(hashMap.values());
```

the ArrayList, valuesList calls the collection hashMap `toArray()` method which essentially does a for loop from 0..N (size) element in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Map, you don't need the loop. Your code can be reduced to :

```
public CachedObject getByIdType( Integer id )
{
    if( id != null )
        return cachedObjectList.get(id);     
    else
        return null;
}
```

This is much more efficient than iterating over all the elements in the List (or all the values in the Map).

Comment: Well my question is little confusing, i don't need loop in getById() but i need it in getByIdType(), my bigest concern is what is the cost of map.values() in that scenario

Comment: You didn't see that first and second getters aren't the same

Comment: @IvanPavić You don't need to call `map.values()` at all. `map.get(id)` already finds the value whose key is id, so if you index the elements of your map by the ID property of `CachedObject` (i.e., when adding an entry to the Map you write `map.put(cachedObj.getId(), cachedObj)`), `map.get(id)` will find the `CachedObject` matching that ID.

Comment: @IvanPavić If you have multiple identifiers by which you wish to index your CachedObjects, you can either have multiple Maps (one for each type of identifier), or (if all the identifiers across all types of identifiers are unique), you can put the same value multiple times in the Map, each time with a different key.

Comment: i know that `getById()` looks like that, and that is Much faster, but sometimes i have to get info from that Map/List by **other property** like `id_type` or `id_other_type` and performance in **those** scenarios are my concern

Comment: well i have considered caching same objects in different maps, but that would make me cache same (1000) objects in tree different maps (in this scenario), is that really the best thing to do??